# Parse Javascript variable value to JSON object

Tags: javascript, wordpress, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I need help printing javascript variable into a JSON object with its value which it has fetched. Please check my code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" data-ampdevmode="">
    var postid = document.querySelector('.status-publish').getAttribute('id').replace("post-", "");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-ampdevmode="">
    console.log(postid);
    </script>
    
 <amp-state id="wpp-json-amp">   

    <script type="application/json" id="wpp-json">
        {
            "ID": postid
        }
        </script>
    </amp-state>
```

Here "postid" will get the id of WordPress post.

Also its not printing the inside content of `<script type="application/json" id="wpp-json">` on amp page.. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: At least in your snippet you are missing an element with the class `status-publish`? Please provide some more code in case that element does exist in the DOM somewhere (if not, that's certainly at least a part of your problem). Please also be more precise what exactly it is you're trying to do? Currently this looks very unusal with a lot of `<script/>` tags but practically almost no code in them, so it's very hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: It will just fetch the postid like a random number.